# achieve to intended query set in django by ORM

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I have below models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
    )
    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=1500,
    )
    writer = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='written_posts',
        related_query_name='written_post',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    klass = models.ForeignKey(
        'klass.Class',
        related_name='posts',
        related_query_name='published_post',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        through='PostUser',
        related_name="posts",
        through_fields=('post', 'user'),
        blank=True,
    )

class PostUser(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='student')
```

and now i want get list of posts that are belong to classes `id=1` or `id=2` and then have PostUser with `user_id=3` and `student_id=4`. i try :

```
Post.objects.filter(klass_id__in=[1,2], users__user__in=[3], users__student__in=[4]).order_by('-create_date').distinct()
```

and another try:

```
qs = PostUser.objects.filter(post__klass_id__in=child.joined_classes_list, user_id=3, student_id=4).order_by('-id').distinct()
result = [obj.post for obj in qs]
```

but i can't achieve to goal and result is wrong,but without any error.thank you

Comment: What is not working with his? Do the `user_id=3` and the `student_id` belong to the *same* `PostUser`?

Comment: thank you for reply. the result not involve all of post that i need. i need posts that exist in class=1 and class=2 that this post have a PostUser instance with post=<mentioned_post> and  `user=3` and `student=4`. for example i can see in admin page that some posts exist in class=1 with user=3 and student=4  but this post isn't exist in result.

Comment: But that `user=3` and `student=4` is for the *same* `PostUser` object, not two `PostUser`s where one has `user=3`, and the other has `student=4`?

Comment: exactly. student and user are for same PostUser

Comment: sorry for my bad English skills. i'm trying to get posts that are belong to specific user and specific student in some classes. this user and student have some related post in every class (user is parent of student , so every parent have some post belong to his child in specific class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use through model then you can access through instance using related name not ManyToManyField related name. in your example you use `__users` points to User model then `__user` point to `PostUser` model.
you can write expected query like this:

```
Post.objects.filter(
    klass_id__in=[1,2], 
    post__user__in=[3],
    post__student__in=[4]
).order_by('-create_date').distinct()
```

Comment: thank you for reply. but error appear `Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: class, description id, klass, klass_id, like_count, post,title, type, users`

Comment: sorry I write wrong related name. see answer again. I fixed it